# Fourier decomposition over finite segment.

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

The question is classical and discussed in any Fourier analysis book, but I have decided to ask it here.

We are studying Fourier Transform on $[-\pi, \pi]$ over $\sin(nx), \cos(nx) $ base. Let $\langle f , g \rangle$ be integration over the interval of the product $f \cdot g$.

I need to prove that coefficients of Fourier transform $f = \sum_{l=1}^N a_l \sin(lx) + \sum_{k=0}^N b_k \cos(kx)$ are

$$a_m = \frac{1}{\pi} \langle f(x), \sin(mx) \rangle , b_m = \frac{1}{\pi}\langle f(x), \cos(mx) \rangle \, m \neq 0 \ \text{and} \ b_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \langle f(x) , 1 \rangle$$

Where does $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$  comes from in case of $b_0$?

Comment: Try computing the various integrals in the right hand sides and see what you get.

Comment: **Hint** What is $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx$$ and so on?

Comment: Check out product to sum formulas for trig functions

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 3):

The trigonometric functions $\sin nx,\cos nx$ have a remarkable property, often referred to as orthogonality$^{1}$ relations:

$$\tag 1 \int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos mx\cos nxdx=\begin{cases} 0&m\neq n\\ \pi&m=n\neq 0\\2\pi&m=n=0\end{cases}$$

$$\tag 2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin mx\cos nxdx=0 \hspace{2 cm}\text{ ...always!}$$

$$\tag 3 \int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin mx\sin nxdx=\begin{cases} 0&m\neq n\\0&m=0,n=0\\ \pi&m=n\neq 0\end{cases}$$

These stem from the product formulae  $$\cos \left( {x + y} \right) = \cos x\cos y - \sin x\sin y$$ and all its relatives give that $$\eqalign{
  & \frac{{\cos \left( {x - y} \right) + \cos \left( {x + y} \right)}}{2} = \cos x\cos y  \cr 
  & \frac{{\cos \left( {x - y} \right) - \cos \left( {x + y} \right)}}{2} = \sin x\sin y  \cr 
  & \frac{{\sin \left( {x + y} \right) + \sin \left( {x - y} \right)}}{2} = \sin x\cos y \cr} $$

This plus the fact that $$\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\cos nxdx}  = \begin{cases}2\pi&n=0\\0&n\geqslant 1\end{cases}$$ $$\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\sin nxdx}  = 0\;\; n=0,1,2,\ldots$$

Give $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$. Using those, we can recover the coefficients as stated above. First, let me write $$f\left( x \right) = \frac{{{b_0}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {{a_n}\sin nx}  + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {{b_m}\cos mx} $$

Then, using the above, we have that $$\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f\left( x \right)\sin jx}  = \frac{{{b_0}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {{a_n}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\sin jx\sin nxdx} }  + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^N {{b_m}\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\sin jx\cos mxdx} } $$

After multiplying by $\sin jx$ for some fixed $j$. Use the above to decide what integrals don't perish, and do the same with $\cos jx$. Remember the consider the possible cases at hand.

---

$1.$ If you has a vector space $V$, one might be lucky enough to be able to endow it with an inner product, $\langle \;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$. If you don't know the "abstract" definition of inner product, just stick to what you know about the usual dot product in $\Bbb R^n$. It turns out that in the space of integrable functions over $[-\pi,\pi]$  we might define an inner product $$(f,g)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$$

(Whether you want Riemann, $L^1$ or $L^2$ is up to you). And we will have a notion of orthogonality, namely that $f\perp g$ if $(f,g)=0$. And this is *really* useful for what you're trying to do. You can read about this in any slightly advanced analysis book.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

Write $\sin, \cos$ as exponentials and use the fact that
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(k-l)x} dx = 2\pi \delta_{kl}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Important trig. identities:**

We have:
\begin{align}
\sin(A+B)&=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\\
\sin(A-B)&=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B\\
\end{align}

Adding:
$$
\sin A\cos B = \frac12(\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B))
$$

So if you ever see $\sin A\cos B$ in an integral, you can change it into $\frac12(\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B))$.

There are two other similar identities which you'll need.  Try adding and subtracting the corresponding expressions for $\cos(A+B)$ and $\cos(A-B)$.

Also remember that if $m$ is an integer then the integral of $sin(mx)$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is $0$, and that the integral of $\cos(mx)$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is $0$ (except for one special value of $m$ -which value?)